# How to stop ggts from adding semicolons to autogenerated groovy code?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I am using [Groovy Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts). Whenever my IDE generates some groovy code it appends it with semicolons automatically, such as when creating import statements.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to tell GGTS to not insert the semicolon right now, but you could set up your formatter to remove semicolons then just format with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F` after you generate code.  From the menu go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Groovy` -> `Formatter` and check `Remove unnecessary semicolons`.

[image]